# Выполнение повторяющейся задачи в фоне

Tags: android, android-service, background-task

Есть повторяемая задача выполняемая в фоне, через заданный краткий промежуток времени. Даже если вынести всю логику в сервис могут возникнуть определенные проблемы например нехватка памяти (процесс будет прибит системой) или sleep устройства. Я конечно понимаю что это так же не очень хорошо для батарейки, но обязательное условие как можно дольше удержать выполнение задачи и перезапустить её в случаи остановки. Хотелось бы узнать общие рекомендации по реализации данной задачи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте [foreground service](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification)) для таких целей, если совсем короткий промежуток.

Или [AlarmManger](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

Comment: А например если устройство ушло в сон, его не надо пытаться пробуждать через PowerManager если используется foreground service?

Comment: @user3910670 если будет уходить в сон используйте `AlarmManager`. Задайте нужный промежуток времени и посылайте `PendingIntent`, который будете обрабатывать в `IntentService`. Еще посмотрите как оптимизировать под Doze (если нужно) http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html